# questions about parameter of template in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I've written my own template function:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> T* begin(T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr;
}
```

when I use an array of string to call it:

```
string str[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
cout << *begin(str) << endl;
```

the compiler will report an error:

```
[Error] call of overloaded 'begin(std::__cxx11::string [3])' is ambiguous
[Note] candidate: T* begin(T (&)[N]) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; long long unsigned int N = 3ull]
```

when I change the parameter type to const :

```
template <typename T, size_t N> T* begin(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    return arr;
}
```

the programm goes normally. How does it happen?
But when I use an array of char to call it again, a new error is reported:

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

So, here comes the question, how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere when your code is used?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I used using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string; before your reply. After I change the declaration to using namespace std; the problem is solved. What does it matter?

Comment: There is `std::begin` standard function. You want to remove `using namespace std`, it's a bad idea. Read the error messages to the end, you will see where the second function is.

Comment: @n.m. Is it included in <iterator>? But I didn't include this header in my code.

Comment: A standard header may include other standard headers, so any one can potentially bring in the (almost) entire standard library. In your case `string` brings it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have this function because it has the same name and signature as one of `std::begin` overloads. Fortunately it also does the very same exact thing, so you can just use `std::begin` instead.

If for some reason you need to use your function, you have to give it a different name, or put it in a namespace of your own.

Note, `using namespace std` is **not** necessary for `std::begin` to be found, because of ADL.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of ADL and I've corrected my code already. I will notice this question in the future.